# Is there a way I could script this scenario with emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Imagine I have an input file,an output file and a file containing some elisp code, which should transform the input file into the output file. Is there a way I could do all this from an external process? Maybe some kind of script mode for emacs? I would like to embed this in a web application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See `emacs --batch` in the [Initial Options](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Initial-Options.html#Initial-Options) section of the manual.  Use it with `-l`, `'f' or`--eval`.  The`batch`option forces`prin1`,`princ`, and`print`to print to stdout and`message`and`error` to print to stderr - so you can actually read and write to pipes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. See `emacs -l` or `emacs --eval`.